# Should we care about NA data in a DataFrame when we use corr.()?

Tags: python, dataframe, correlation, na

I try to calculate the correlation matrix of a DataFrame. But I'm so confused that should we replace all NA data with 0 or just remove them? In other words, will NA data affect the calculation of correlation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the correlation values to classify data sets based on whether or not they correlate, sure, you could treat the NaN as 0. Perhaps a better way to interpret a NaN output is "not interpretable" or "not meaningful" whereas a significant correlation of 0 means "no correlation"

Also refer this:

- [python - how to compute correlation-matrix with nans in data-matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27104056/14045537)
- [How to efficiently get the correlation matrix (with p-values) of a data frame with NaN values?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38001888/14045537)